# What is the center of mass of the liquid with a density of $10 -x^{2}$ in a cone? (drawing included)

Tags: calculus

**Problem:**

A straight circular cone with the height $2$ m and the radius $1$ m has the pointy end downward and is filled with a liquid. In a flat plane parallel with the bottom surface of the cone and at a distance of $x$ m from the pointy end, the density of the liquid is $\rho$ $kg/m^3$ with:

$\rho = 10- x^2$

Determine the center of mass of the liquid.

**Attempted solution:**

Not the prettiest picture I have ever drawn:

[image]

The basic idea is to get the area of a slice:

$$A(r) = r^2 \pi$$

Congruence gives the radius:

$$\frac{r}{x} = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow r = \frac{x}{2}$$

The area becomes:

$$A(x) = \pi \Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2 = \frac{\pi x^2}{4}$$

The volume slice becomes:

$$dV = A(x)dx$$

The dm slice becomes:

$$dm = \rho \pi r^2 dx = \frac{\rho \pi x^2}{4}$$

So left to do is to calculate two integrals from $0$ to $2$ (for $x dm$ and $dm$) and divide the first with the second.

$$\int_0^2 x dm = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^2 \rho x^3 dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^2 (10-x^2) x^3 dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \Big( \frac{10x^4}{4} - \frac{x^6}{6} \Big)  \Big|_0^2 = \frac{22\pi}{3}$$

$$\int_0^2 dm = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^2 (10-x^2) dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \Big( 10x- \frac{x^3}{3} \Big)  \Big|_0^2 = \frac{13\pi}{3}$$

Division produces the final answer of:

$$\frac{22}{13}$$

The expected answer is:

$$\frac{55}{38} \approx 1.45$$

length units from pointy end of the cone.

Where did I go wrong and what are some productive ways to finish off this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks good but there is a mistake in the integrand:$$\int_0^2 dm = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^2 (10-x^2) \color{red}{x^2}dx = \cdots$$